# Tinymce Enter key

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tinymce

In my application i'm using Tinymce. Here my problem is.

### Scenario 1

1) i have paragraph with style like this

```
<div class="p">Paragraph with some content.<!--p--></div>
```

when i place the cursor at the end of the paragraph and press the enter key then it will create like this

```
<div class="p">Paragraph with some content.<!--p--></div>
<div class="p"></div>
```

But i need like this

```
<div class="p"><!--p--></div>
```

### Scenario 2

1) I have paragraph with style like this

```
<div class="p">Paragraph with some content.<!--p--></div>
```

when i place the cursor at the middle of the paragraph and press the enter then it will create like this

```
<div class="p">Paragraph with <!--p--></div><div class"p">some content.<!--p--></div>
```

For obtain this i'm using function like this

```
ed.onKeyPress.addToTop(function(ed, e) {
if ((e.charCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)) { 
 tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand('abb_ifr',"mceInsertContent",true,'<!--p--></div>');
 }
  });
```

I need achieve Scenario 1 .How can i do it in Tinymce . Do i need to change anything in core file. Please advise me.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question... but isn't Shift+enter what you want to achieve?

Comment: well i need to do it in Enter key. Not Shift+Enter

Comment: do you want to give the class to all paragraphs in the ditor or just the new one that is created?

Comment: `addToTop` unfortunately does not work in the 4.x branch anymore

Answer (score 4):

After your reply, I assume the problem is indeed with the linebreaks. If it is not, please specify your question then.

But to have the enter key jump down just one line, use this

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '' // Needed for 3.x
});
```

So it will create one big paragraph with several line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        forced_root_block : false
});
```